# View headers on iphone

Tags: mobile, safari, http-headers

I have been trying to view the headers of a website on Iphone. I cannot figure out a way to see the headers on Iphone safari. Anybody got any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the step-by-step documentation on [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-debug-on-iphone). It shows how to enable and make use of the Safari Developer Tools.

Make sure you connect your iOS device to your computer *(by USB is recommended)* in order to be able to allow your computer to directly communicate with the iOS device.